# clicking a checkbox and applying class to it's parent

Tags: jquery, forms, checkbox, toggleclass

I'm trying to apply a class to a li element if the input box is checked but I can't work out why it's not happening. The HTML and CSS is 'by others' so I'm sure there's an error there as the jQuery alone.

The HTML is

```
<ol class="subproduct">
<li>
    <input type="checkbox" name="extra2" value="tested" />
    <p class="checkbox"></p>
    <h3>test <span class="price">5</h3>
    <p>word words words</p>
</li>
<li>
    <input type="checkbox" name="extra2" value="tested" />
    <p class="checkbox"></p>
    <h3>test <span class="price">5</h3>
    <p>word words words</p>
</li>
<li>
    <input type="checkbox" name="extra2" value="tested" />
    <p class="checkbox"></p>
    <h3>test <span class="price">5</h3>
    <p>word words words</p>
</li>
<li>
    <input type="checkbox" name="extra2" value="tested" />
    <p class="checkbox"></p>
    <h3>test <span class="price">5</h3>
    <p>word words words</p>
</li>
```

the Jquery for this is

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input:checkbox').change(function(){
         if($(this).is(":checked")) {
             $('.subproduct li').addClass("checked");
         } else {
             $('.subproduct li').removeClass("checked");
         }
    });
});
```

I've created a little JSFiddle with all the CSS and the HTML - http://jsfiddle.net/sturobson/gG8Qr/

I'm sure there's some over specifity or something? Basically if the checkbox is checked I want to add/remove a class to the .subproduct li

But the current code isn't working. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to go down the DOM insteed of selecting all `.subproduct li` elements. Use jQuery parent, next or prev functions for this. In your example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input:checkbox').change(function(){
         if($(this).is(":checked")) {
             $(this).parent().addClass("checked");
         } else {
             $(this).parent().removeClass("checked");
         }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

your are checking if the check bocx is checked or not... and then if checked, you are adding class to all the `<li>`.. use `parent()` to get that particular `<li>` and ..use add or remove class..
use parent();

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input:checkbox').change(function(){
    if($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $(this).parent().addClass("checked");
    } else {
         $(this).parent().removeClass("checked");
    }
  });
});
```

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/bipen/gG8Qr/1/)

Answer (score 1):

You are always assigning the class to all `li` elements.
Try only assigning it to the direct parenting `li` using jQuery [**parent()**](http://api.jquery.com/parent), similar to this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input:checkbox').change(function(){
        if($(this).is(":checked")) {
            $(this).parent("li").addClass("checked");
        } else {
            $(this).parent("li").removeClass("checked");
        }
    });
});
```

or if you want to always assign the class to the parent regardless of it being an `li` or not you can use just `parent()` similar to the below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input:checkbox').change(function(){
        if($(this).is(":checked")) {
            $(this).parent().addClass("checked");
        } else {
            $(this).parent().removeClass("checked");
        }
    });
});
```

---

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/gG8Qr/4/) - Assign class only to parent `li`

---